# Installation of Windows Issues

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot

Lately my computer's SATA controllers ceased working, so I moved my HDD to a new setup I had lying around to use it. Well, from trying to use said HDD with the faulty setup, I must have corrupted the OS or something of the like as it is now not recognized as a boot disk. With this knowledge, I made a boot disk with Microsoft's tools, however it is telling me it is unable to install Windows 10: "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. the selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI system, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks."

My questions: How do I fix this issue? Is it possible to do without losing the data on the HDD (I can lose it if I must, but prefer not to.)?

Comment: Convert your MBR disk to GPT or get rid of your partitions, and just let the installer, create the GPT partitions

Comment: @Ramhound How do I convert my MBR disk to GPT and/or get rid of partitions? Will doing so cause data loss?

Comment: Depends on the current state of the system but, yes, it's possible to convert MBR to GPT but your trying to install Windows 10 on the hdd which would result in data loss depending on which version you were using

Answer (score -1):

the steps to solve this problem as proposed in here:

[Windows cannot be installed to this disk. the selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI system, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-cannot-be-installed-to-this-disk-the/741969ff-95e0-4d00-b55d-db3a75831cb8?auth=1)

> There is a simple way to fix this :
>
> Follow these steps if the hard disk volume size is less than 2.19 TB:
>
> A. Temporarily disable the EFI Boot Sources setting in the BIOS:
>
> 1. Restart the computer, and then press F10 to enter the BIOS.
> 2. Navigate to Storage > Boot Order , and then disable the EFI Boot
>      Sources .
> 3. Select File > Save Changes > Exit .
>
> B. Install the Windows operating system.
>
> C. Enable the EFI Boot Sources setting in the BIOS:
>
> 1. Restart the computer, and then press F10 to enter the BIOS.
> 2. Navigate to Storage > Boot Order , and then enable the EFI Boot
>      Sources .
> 3. Select File > Save Changes > Exit .
>
> Follow these steps if the hard disk volume size is greater than 2.19
>   TB:
>
> Follow the steps in the Microsoft document titled "How to Configure
>   UEFI/GPT-Based Hard Drive Partitions" (in English) to create a GPT
>   partition

Comment: You should quote the portion of your answer that you are quoting

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). 
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.